# Chrome dev tools to emulate mobile devices with navigation bar

Tags: android, html, css, iphone, google-chrome

Hey I'm a web developer and I'm looking for a way to emulate mobile devices which also displays their respective navigation bars, toolbars etc. In the 'Device toolbar' in Google Chrome (v58 on macOS) there's a specific mode available for the Nexus 5X (and  ['supported devices', according to Google](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports)), which is exactly what I'm looking for (see screenshot below), however I can't seem to find a way to turn this on for other devices (such as iPhones, Galaxys etc).

Of course these bars would differ between the devices and the browser that it's running, so ideally I'm looking for a way to manually specify the height of the bars and how they interact with the viewport (e.g. iOS Safari includes the top bar in the viewport height calculation but leaves out the bottom bar, which kinda screws with how the bottom of the page is being displayed (as discussed [here](https://nicolas-hoizey.com/2015/02/viewport-height-is-taller-than-the-visible-part-of-the-document-in-some-mobile-browsers.html))).

Ultimately what I'm trying to achieve is a way to accurately simulate how a website would look on a specific device, by instead of looking at just screen sizes and pixel density actually taking in to account that there are other sections being displayed on the screen which of course takes up screen realestate themselves and affect the appearance and user experience.

All ideas are welcome =)

[image]

Comment: Nonsense. He described the problem and what he had done so far to solve it. He's asking for possible next steps to improve his workflow. Solutions *could* include, but are not limited to, external resources. I think what we are seeing here are admins trying to gain points by blocking useful questions.

Comment: So here is an answer: if you can use your own build of *the-software-your-question-is-about* , you want to look at this directory: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/emulated_devices/ . adding images there and describing those in module.json should give you more previews like the Nexus.

Comment: Why is this closed? I came here speciffically looking for a solution to this problem, how to emulate top and bottom bar on iPhone. If it had an answer, I'd be done and over with this already, gained knowledge and could continue working. Isn't this the whole principle of this site? To share the knowledge and help each other? Unblock this please.

Comment: Me too, I'm looking for the same answer!

Comment: This is an important problem that web developers meet day to day - this question it is relevant and in no way trivial to solve. There is no book or tutorial for this topic.

Comment:  Unfortunately, virtual keyboard support is deprecated in Chrome 68+.

Comment: Also don't see why this question got closed??

Answer (score 9):

You can use Blisk browser, it's built on Chromium and supports toolbars and panels for IOS/Android devices, it has a good set of devices that you can emulate on.

Comment: Nice dev browser but it does not emulate the viewport height change when hiding browser top bar like on real devices

Comment: Too bad that's precisely what most people need: having the viewport change emulated :(